# Kivy, how to use datas in canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I've a list of products and I wanna display it with Labels.
I know how to fetch datas from TextInput but now i wanna display my list in canvas.

How can you do it ?

**EDIT:**

I have datas like this in 'global':

```
products = [{'name' : 'Coca' , 'price' : 1.8000},{'name' : 'Fanta' ,
'price' : 1.8000}]
```

And i want to display in a `GridLayout` 2 cols, x rows, 2 labels, 1 for the name and an other for price of Fanta, Coca and others ...

```
<CommandeScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: 'Coca'
        Label:
            text: '1.80 euros'
        Button:
            text: 'Orangina'
        Label:
            text: '1.80 euros'
        Button:
            text: 'Ajouter'
        Button:
            text: 'Quitter'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

Comment: You want to create many labels and show them in window, that's it? please consider to put some code

Comment: EDITED, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to go is to add it in Python code in the class definition:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CommandeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CommandeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        products = [{'name' : 'Coca' , 'price' : 1.8000},{'name' : 'Fanta' ,
'price' : 1.8000}]
        for p in products:
            self.gl.add_widget(Label(text=p['name']))
            self.gl.add_widget(Label(text=str(p['price']))
```

In kv, it will be like that:

```
<CommandeScreen>:
    gl: GL
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        GridLayout:
            id: GL
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: 'Prix : '
            Label:
                text: 'In euros'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: 'Ajouter'
            Button:
                text: 'Quitter'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

Result will be:

[image: kivy labels]